# Exporting GIF in photoshop background isn't smooth - Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, creative-cloud

I've exported a GIF from photoshop but when I uploaded it to my behance platform the background isn't smooth? I use save for web but am not sure what preset I need to set it to so this doesn't happen. I just went with the default option which was provided.

*NOTE: This is for an animated GIF that flicks through pictures

[image]

Comment: When one "uploads" an image to a web site, the site customarily performs some "post processing" on the upload - things like resizing and recompressing the uploaded image. They essentially generate a *new* image. What you upload is *not* what is seen on the site. Trying to circumnavigate each site's unique post processing is something that often entails reviewing *that site's* guidelines for uploads. I do not know if anything is animated in your image, if nothing is animated, I'd use jpg or png, not gif.

Comment: Is this for an animated gif?  If not, then use jpeg or png instead.  If you need to export an animated gif, then make sure you enable dithering when exporting. That will help break up the banding, you may also need to increase the number of colours.  Too few colours will cause banding.

Comment: OK, thanks for the update/edit.  Did you try doing as I suggested, enable dithering and increase the number of colours when exporting the gif?

Answer (score 0):

The background can not be smooth, because of the limited palette; it is posterized.

An animated gif of this nature consumes a lot of the limited number of colors you have, so you are using let's say 20 levels of red.

Put a flat 1 color on the background and the gif will use just 1 color.

---

Revisiting this question:

Here is a simplification of your image.

You can have only 256 colors per frame. With this gradient let's say you use 4 tones of red for the background and the rest for the product and hand (The white and the remaining gray spaces)

[image]

The first image is with a smooth gradient because it is a "true color". No limitation on the palette, but as soon as you have the limitation you have two options. Or have the posterization (Image 2) or add some dithering (Image 3) which increases the file size.

---

But now you have an animation. The flicker is due to the inconsistency between the palettes of each frame.

Imagine that in one frame you have a red product. Then the program can think that it can use the new reds present to dither differently the background. You have a flicker.

---

The solution for the flicker is to use a fixed palette on the entire animation.

[image]

Then every frame is forced to use the same colors, so it will use the same reds for the background.

In this image, I am using a "standard" palette.

Comment: so to be more clear (the answer and comments to the question hint at this): GIF only supports a maximum of 256-colors using an indexed palette. This is not enough to accurately reproduce a photo.

Comment: I edited the answer significantly.